# Wrap find and replace text in MS Word Shape with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've started a VBA script that does a wildcard find/replace and (A) surrounds each found iteration of text in a different colored border and then (B) replaces the reference characters with a blank space. But for (A), I want to add the found iteration of text to a specific Word shape instead of adding a colored border. Below is my code so far. Can you provide guidance on how I could add the found text to an MS Word shape using VBA within the script below?

```
Sub findAndFormatRanking()
'FORMAT RANKING 1
'Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "11_*_11"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
While Selection.Find.Execute

    Selection.Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorGreen
    Selection.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    Selection.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth300pt
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdGreen
Wend
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "11_"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "_11"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

UPDATE ON CLARIFICATION 4/6/2016: In my While Loop above, while it is finding the matching text between symbols, I want to replace my 3 lines of code add-border color snippet with a snippet on adding/drawing a shape around my selection. If you do not think this is possible, please let me know and I'll close out this question.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the Shape. How to identify it? Is it the kind of Shape that can accept text content (a Drawing object) or are you thinking about trying to put text "on top" of some other kind of object?

Comment: Hi Cindy. Of the 2 options you outlined, which one woulld be best practice? (I'm assuming the drawing object is best)

Comment: Drawing object, definitely. But you still haven't told us how to *identify* that Shape in the document...

Comment: With this shape: Shapes.Range(Array("Snip Single Corner Rectangle 3"))

Comment: What's with the Array? An array is not a Shape, it's a bunch of Shapes. And please use the [edit] link below your question to add additional information, rather than putting it in Comments.